# ANOVA with quantile regression: interpretation

Tags: r, anova, categorical-data, p-value, quantile-regression

I asked a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74002610/10531881) on how to figure whether multiple models are significantly different or not.

> To compare two models using `anova` in R, I can simply use `anova(model1,model2)` and conclude whether they are significantly different or not based on the p-value returned. However, currently I have data such that-

```
Cities     Localities     x1     x2     y1
City1           .          .      .      .
City1           .          .      .      .
City2           .          .      .      .
City2           .          .      .      .
City2           .          .      .      .
City3           .          .      .      .
City4           .          .      .      .
City4           .          .      .      .
City4           .          .      .      .
```

> and so on. I want to show that there is variability between cities as groups without comparing the models for each subgroup pairwise.

The solution I got was using `anova(model1,model2)` where `model1: y1~x1+x2` and `y2~x1+x2+Cities`. However, I am using a quantile regression model to fit data and for some reason no matter what order I put for `model1` and `model2`, I am getting this:

[image]

How am I supposed to interpret this? Note that the third explanatory variable in `model2` is nominal categorical (like IDs).

Comment: By looking at R `quantreg:::logLik` it appears that the log likelihood is from a binomial likelihood, i.e., just uses counting as does the quantile regression estimation process.  So it's going to give rise to an inefficient test (as opposed to what you get from ordinal regression).  When I run `anova` on two models I get an $F$ statistic as you do, but likellihood methods are supposed to generate $\chi^2$ statistics, not $F$ statistics, so I don't know what is going on.  This is probably covered in Koenker's book.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Then, what should I do in case I have nominal data and I want to check variability within that?

Comment: Quantile regression only works on highly continuous Y.  Are you referring to nominal X?  The type of X has no bearing on the choice of tests.  Likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ tests are always good defaults, but I don't think quantile regression in its current form lends itself to efficient likelihood ratio tests.

Comment: @FrankHarrell X itself is not nominal but what I wanted to check was whether there is variability within submatrices of X; where the X matrix is divided observationwise (not columnwise)